# Facebook dynamic product ads feed issues

Tags: facebook, dynamic, product, ads, feed

I am trying to setup facebook Dynamic product ads. Facebook says they accept same feed that google accepts at their google merchant centre for google shopping.

I have uploaded google shopping feed to Facebook and it comes back with following error

"Incorrectly formatted property: shipping (1,529 products affected)
Property shipping is incorrectly formatted."

Facebook's documentation says it needs shipping data in this format

COUNTRY:STATE:SHIPPING_TYPE:PRICE

US:CA:Ground:9.99 USD,
US:NY:Air:15.99 USD

Here is what facebook pics from google feed.

GB::24hr Tracked Insured Signed (Excludes Saturday, Sunday, Bank Holidays):0

It seems to correct to me as per facebook documentation. Any idea what could be wrong here?

Second question is how do you set it up if you offer "Worldwide free shipping"

Comment: Read how to ask a question will you http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - this is beyond help on so many levels!

Comment: You can't have commas (,) inside Shipping type. Comma (,) is used to between different shipping alternatives

Comment: @WizKid thanks... that helps. Please post it as answer and I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have commas (,) inside Shipping type. Comma (,) is used to between different shipping alternatives